# When to cluster a table using an index? [postgresql]

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/sql-cluster.html

Now suppose I have pg_repack installed so that it won't lock the table when clustering.

1. Should you cluster a table using an index that has a high idx_scan?
2. It does not make sense to cluster a unique uuid index right? Since reordering the table won't help to retrieve information easily.
3. Would it make sense to do a cluster on a composite unique index?
4. If a particular column has been joined (inner/left) with several queries, would it make sense to cluster a table related to the column's index?
5. What exactly we should look for when selecting a particular index to cluster a table on?

Answer (score 2):

If the index that you use for clustering is on column `col` of table `public.tab`, run

```
SELECT correlation
FROM pg_stats
WHERE schemaname = 'public' AND tablename = 'tab'
  AND attname = 'col';
```

If that value is 1.0, the order is perfect, if it is close to 0, the order has rotted. You best use trial and error to find from what value of `correlation` on performance gets bad.